# How to remove from an array the elements that are present in a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to clean an array (**secondArray**) by removing those elements that are also included in another array (**secondRegex**). This is one of my latest attempts, but it doesn't work :'( The result I get is: 0[]. Why????????

```
const secondRegex = ['i', 'a', 'about', 'am', 'an', 'are', 'as', 'at', 'be', 'by', 'for', 'from', 'how', 'in', 'is', 'it', 'of', 'on', 'or', 'that', 'the', 'this', 'to', 'was', 'what', 'when', 'where', 'who', 'will', 'with'];
const secondArray = ['i', 'am','a', 'very', 'happy', 'child'];

let myList = []
for (let i = 0; i < secondArray; i++){
    let is_the_same = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < secondRegex; j++){
        if(secondArray[i] == secondRegex[j]){
            is_the_same = 1;
            break;

        }
    }if (!is_the_same){
        myList.push(secondArray[i]);
    }
}
console.log(myList);
```

I have also tried this with no success:

```
for (let i = 0; i < secondArray.length; i++){
    let value = secondArray[i];
    let coincidence = secondArray.some(value => secondRegex.includes(value));
    }if (coincidence = true){
        continue;
    }
    else{
    myList.push(secondArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it can help you with your issue.

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < secondArray; i++){` You want `for (let i = 0; i < secondArray.length; i++){` Same with inner loop.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuu!!!!!!